# Scalar Triple Product Exercise

Tags: vector-analysis

Show that if $a,b,c,d\in{\mathbb R}^3$, then
$d= $$\frac{ [(b\times c)\cdot d]a +
 [(c\times a)\cdot d]b +
 [(a\times b)\cdot d]c} {
 [(a\times b)\cdot c]}
$

If $a=\left ( x_{1},x_{2},x_{3} \right )$, $b=\left ( y_{1},y_{2},y_{3} \right )$, $c=\left ( z_{1},z_{2},z_{3} \right )$ and $d=\left ( w_{1},w_{2},w_{3} \right )$, it is clear that the proposed exercise is demonstrated, my question is, if there is another way for your demonstration.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First show that it holds for the standard basis $a, b, c$ and every $d$. 
Then show it still holds if any of $a, b, c$ is multiplied by a nonzero scalar. 
Then show it still holds when e.g. $a$ is exchanged to $a+b$, and in all similar cases. 
Finally, by these elementary operations, we can arrive to any $a, b, c$ with nonzero determinant.